# Can we define probability of an event involving an infinite number of random variables?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Consider a collection $(X_a)_{a\in[0,1]}$ of i.i.d. random variables following the uniform distribution on [0,1]. That is, for every real number $a \in [0,1]$ we have a random variable $X_a$. Can we meaningfully define the probability of the event "at least one of the variables $X_a$ *equals* $1/2$"? And if so, what is that probability?

Comment: What is the measure on an uncountable product? And  note $a\in[0,1]$ should ignore the topology of $[0,1]$

Comment: @ posilon : for the probability of an event to make sense, you first have to define the sigma algebra you are working on and then define the probability measure over it. Here I feel that the cylindrical sigma-algebra is natural and the probability measure, the one defined by the finite dimensionnal laws of $X_a$'s. In this context I am not even sure that your event is measurable. Best regards

Answer (score 4):

Hi following my comment I think the answer is no for the cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{C}$ and  probability measure implied by finite dimensional laws of $X_a$'s.

Using the lemma in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508767/generated-sigma-algebras-with-cylinder-set-doesnt-contain-the-space-of-conti) :

If $A=\{\exists a\in [0,1]$ $s.t. X_a=1/2\}\in \mathcal{C}$ then there would exist a countable set $S\in [0,1]$ caracterizing $A$. Meaning that for two  elements of $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$, $\omega$ and $\omega'$ with $\omega \in A$ such that $X_s(\omega)= X_s(\omega')$, $\forall s\in S$, then $\omega' \in A$ too.

So let's take $\omega \in A$ equal to $0$ except for one point $a$ not in $S$ where $X_a=1/2$ so that $\omega$ is really in $A$. Now by our lemma, this would imply that $\omega'$ defined by $X_t=0$ for all $t\in [0,1]$ would be in $A$ too but this is false, implying that $A$ is a non-measurable event for the cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{C}$.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we have a countable collection of r.v.'s, $0 \leq P(\cup_i X_i=.5)\leq \sum_1^\infty P(X_i=.5) \leq \sum_1^\infty 0 = 0$. If the collection is infinite, then I feel confident some thing weird will happen.

Comment: $(X_a)_{a\in [0,1]}$ is not a countable collection of random variables, and hence this does not answer the question.

Comment: @user710587 Thank you for your answer but I am interested in the case where the cardinality of the collection of the random variables is no smaller than the cardinality of the sample space of each variable. My intuitive question is if the one infinity cancels the other.

Comment: Well, the uncountable union of null sets can be infinite, if you consider Lebesgue measure and singletons.  We know that $P(.5-\epsilon \leq X_i \leq .5+\epsilon) = 2\epsilon$, so that $P(\cup_\alpha X_\alpha \in (.5-\epsilon,.5+\epsilon)) \geq P(\cup_k^\infty X_i \in (.5-\epsilon,.5+\epsilon)) \geq P(X_k \in (.5-\epsilon,.5+\epsilon))\geq 2\epsilon$.  This implies in some sense that $\limsup_\alpha P(X_\alpha \in (.5-\epsilon,.5+\epsilon)) \geq 2\epsilon$, regardless of the ordering.  This bound doesn't seem to help us :(.