# Continuous path of stochastic processes

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

In my probability book a stochastic process is defined as a measurable map $X: \Omega \rightarrow S^T,$ where $S^T$ is equipped with the sigma algebra of cylinder events. Our professor mentioned that the canonical image space of $X$ with its sigma algebra may be a bad choice in many situations, as plenty of events are not measurable w.r.t. this sigma-algebra.

Now, a stochastic process is continuous, if 
$$P(\{\omega; t \mapsto X(\omega,t) \text{ is continuous}\})=1.$$

What I don't understand is: Why is this event measurable?

Or differently: If you read such a definition of a stochastic process, what kind of definition of stochastic processes do you have in mind such that all of this makes sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right; the event

$$\{\omega; t \mapsto X_t(\omega) \, \text{is continuous}\}$$

is, in general, not measurable - this is because the set of continuous functions is not contained in the sigma algebra of cylinder sets, see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/508767/).

There are at least two ways to evade this measurability issue:

1. We say that $X$ has almost surely continuous sample paths if there exists a measurable $P$-null set $N$ such that $$\{\omega; t \mapsto X_t(\omega) \, \text{is not continuous}\} \subseteq N.$$
2. Instead of considering $X$ as a mapping $X: \Omega \to S^T$ we *assume* that $X: \Omega \to C^T$ where $C^T$ denotes the set of continuous functions $f: T \to S$. Moreover, we endow $C^T$ with the trace $\sigma$-algebra of the cylinder sets.

Comment: I have difficulties understanding the second appoach. If you know that $X$ is a mapping into the continuous functions, then you know that it is a continuous function for any $\omega.$ So I see a problem with this approach: You require $P(t \mapsto X_t)=1$ is continuous, but you already assume this in your definition. So in that case, the requirement is rather redundant, don't you think?

Comment: @user167575 The only assumption is that $X$ maps $\Omega$ to $C^T$... this implies automatically that all sample paths are continuous. (in particular, if we use this approach, we don't need a probability measure on $\Omega$ to talk about continuity.)

Comment: okay, but I feel as if this is an even stronger requirement, as we have continuity not only a.e., but everywhere. So for instance: Is it possible require in the case of Brownian motion that $B: \Omega \rightarrow C^T$?

Comment: @user167575 Yes, in the case of Brownian motion it works very well. The point is basically: Assume $X$ is a process with almost surely continuous sample paths (e.g. in the sense which I suggested in the first approach). Then we can define a new process $Y$ by setting $$Y(\omega) := \begin{cases} X(\omega), & \text{if $X(\omega)$ is continuous} \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}.$$ Then, we have $Y: \Omega \to C^T$. Since $X$ has almost surely continuous sample paths, the processes $X$ and $Y$ are "almost the same" ... so, roughly, instead of $X$ we can consider $Y$.