# why $\{\omega \mid t\mapsto \omega (t)\ continuous\}$ not measurable?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F)$ where $\Omega =\{\omega \mid \omega :[0,\infty )\to \mathbb R\text{ is a function}\}$ and $\mathcal F$ generated by cylinders, i.e. of the form $\{\omega \mid (\omega (t_1),...,\omega (t_n))\in B\}$ for some Borel set $B\subset \mathbb R^n$. Let $$C=\{\omega \mid t\mapsto \omega (t)\text{ continuous}\}.$$

Why $C$ is not measurable ? I tried by contradiction. If it's measurable, then there is a $B\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)^{\mathbb N}$ and a sequence $(t_i)$ of $[0,\infty )$ s.t. $$C=\{\omega \mid (\omega (t_i))_{i\in\mathbb N}\in B\}.$$
I don't see where there is a contradiction.

Comment: are there any conditions on $t_1 \ldots t_n$ and/or $B$?

Comment: @Interestedstudent: what do you me mean ? $(t_i)$ is a sequence of $[0,\infty )$ and $B$ is in $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)^{\mathbb N}$. It's the definition of being measurable...

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/508767/36150)