# Is $C(\mathbb{R})\subset \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Equip $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ with the cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{C}$ and view $C(\mathbb{R})$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$.

**Question**: Is $C(\mathbb{R})\in \mathcal{C}$?

---

- The cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra is defined as follows: Define $ \hat x:\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $\hat x(f)= f(x)$. Then $\mathcal{C}=\sigma(\hat x : x\in \mathbb{R})$.
- Equip $C(\mathbb{R})$ with the topology of uniform convergence on compacts and denote $\mathcal{B}$ the corresponding Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Then the inclusion $\iota:(C(\mathbb{R}),\mathcal{B})\rightarrow ( \mathbb{R}^ \mathbb{R},\mathcal{C})$ is measurable and we even have $\iota^{-1}(\mathcal{C})=\mathcal{B}$. - that much I know. The question above may thus be reformulated as '*is $\iota$ bimeasurable*?'
- My motivation is the following: I want to know whether there is an easy way to check whether a measure $\nu$ on $( \mathbb{R}^ \mathbb{R},\mathcal{C})$ is given as the push-forward $\nu =\iota_*\mu$ of a  Borel-measure $\mu$ on $C(\mathbb{R}).$ If the answer to the question above is positive, then the condition for this is simply that $\nu(\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}\backslash C(\mathbb{R})) =0$.
- It seems like this issue should be discussed in the context of stochastic processes - but e.g. in Dudley's book I didn't find anything. Namely, if $(X_t:t\in  \mathbb{R})$ is a stochastic process (in $ \mathbb{R}$), then 'sample continuous' is sometime defined as the condition
  $$
  \mathbb{P}(\omega: t\mapsto X_t(\omega) \text{ is continuous}) =1.
  $$
  However, if we first view $X$ as a random variable in $( \mathbb{R}^ \mathbb{R},\mathcal{C})$, then the event can be rewritten as $E=\{\omega: X(\omega)\in C(\mathbb{R})\}$ and we would need this to be measurable to make sense of its probability. In general $E$ is only measurable if $C(\mathbb{R})\in \mathcal{C}$. I suppose one could circumvent this by asking for a measurable subset $E'\subset E$ of probability one instead.

Comment: It has already been answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508767/generated-sigma-algebras-with-cylinder-set-doesnt-contain-the-space-of-conti

Comment: This comment addresses the last two points: In general if $S$ is a separable, locally convex space that injects continuously into $C(\mathbb{R})$, then the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $S$ is generated by the evaluation functionals $\hat t:S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, u \mapsto u(t)$ (see e.g. Bogachev's book on Gaussian measures).

Comment: Now if $\mu$ is a measure on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ such that there exists a random variable $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ with law $\mu$ and such that $X(\omega)\in S$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$ (this is the careful formulation of the existence of a version with sample paths in $S$), then we can factor $X=\iota \circ \hat X$, where $\iota:S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ is the inclusion. Now $\hat t \circ \hat X = \hat t \circ \iota \circ X$ is measurable on $\Omega$ (where measurability of $\iota$ follows from the considerations above) and thus $\hat X$ is measurable!

Comment: Here measurability of $\hat X$ is meant as a map from $\Omega$ to $S$, the latter equipped with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Consequently the push-forward $\nu = \hat X_*\mathbb{P}$ defines a Borel probability measure on the space $S$ with the property that $\iota_*\nu = \mu$.